# Как исправить ошибку «Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB'»?

Tags: php, mysql

Что делать если RedBeanphp идеально работает на локалке, и абсолютно не работает на удалённом сервере. С подключение к базе всё нормально, проверял и не раз.
Вот ошибка что высвечивается:

Fatal error: Uncaught [42000] - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1286 Unknown storage engine 'InnoDB' trace: #0 /profiles/p/pu/put/putishestvinik/putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/rb.php(958): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->runQuery('CREATE TABLE `u...', Array) #1 /profiles/p/pu/put/putishestvinik/putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/rb.php(3455): RedBeanPHP\Driver\RPDO->Execute('CREATE TABLE`u...', Array) #2 /profiles/p/pu/put/putishestvinik/putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/rb.php(5690): RedBeanPHP\Adapter\DBAdapter->exec('CREATE TABLE `u...') #3 /profiles/p/pu/put/putishestvinik/putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/rb.php(7505): RedBeanPHP\QueryWriter\MySQL->createTable('`user`') #4 /profiles/p/pu/put/putishestvinik/putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/rb.php(7634): RedBeanPHP\Repository\Fluid->createTableIfNotExists(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean), 'user') #5 /profiles/p/pu/put/putishestvinik/putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/rb.php(7233): RedBeanPHP\Repository\Fluid->storeBean(Object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean)) #6 /profiles/p/pu/put/putishestvinik/putishestvinik.zzz.com. in /profiles/p/pu/put/putishestvinik/putishestvinik.zzz.com.ua/rb.php on line 720

Помогите кто разбирается пожалуйста, мучаюсь уже пару дней над этой ОРМ

Comment: Орм ни причем. На сервере, видимо, не подключен InnoDB. Что странно, поскольку этот движок сейчас в mysql по умолчанию. Возможно у вас на сервере старая версия или при установке был отключен движок InnoDB. Сложно сказать не зная: ОС сервера, конфиг mysql на сервере

Comment: Здравствуйте. Спасибо за ваш комментарий. Спросил я у техподдержки своего хостинга то сказали что версия mysqlnd 5.0.11. Возможно ли как-то исправить эту ошибку, или она напрямую зависит от версии mysql??? хостинг даёт доступ лишь к одной базе данных... могу ли я сам обновить версию?

Comment: написал в ответе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала проверьте, что InnoDB вообще присутствует в установке

```
mysql> show engines;
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| Engine             | Support | Comment                                                        | Transactions | XA   | Savepoints |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
| InnoDB             | DEFAULT | Supports transactions, row-level locking, and foreign keys     | YES          | YES  | YES        |
| CSV                | YES     | CSV storage engine                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MyISAM             | YES     | MyISAM storage engine                                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| BLACKHOLE          | YES     | /dev/null storage engine (anything you write to it disappears) | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MRG_MYISAM         | YES     | Collection of identical MyISAM tables                          | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| MEMORY             | YES     | Hash based, stored in memory, useful for temporary tables      | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| ARCHIVE            | YES     | Archive storage engine                                         | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA | YES     | Performance Schema                                             | NO           | NO   | NO         |
| FEDERATED          | NO      | Federated MySQL storage engine                                 | NULL         | NULL | NULL       |
+--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------+------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

если отсутствует, то только владелец хостинга может установить поддержку InnoDB или перекомпилировать с поддержкой InnoDB (в зависимости от системы).

Если присутствует, то надо посмотреть в конфиге БД, не включен ли там параметр

```
skip-innodb
```

В любом случае, только администратор хостинга может проделать эти операции

mysqlnd 5.0.11 - это не версия сервера, это версия PHP библиотеки для работы с mysql,

Comment: Да, скорее всего нужно ждать обновления mysql :(

Comment: Какой-то у вас древний хостинг. Уже лет +/- 10, как все распространенные фреймворки требуют InnoDB, поскольку только в этом движке поддерживаются транзакции и внешние ключи